# Reverse EBCDIC sorts numbers before letters in ROW_NUMBER function

Tags: sql, sorting, db2, ebcdic

So I do have following SQL select

```
SELECT FOO.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KEY ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM FOO
```

[image]

Key is of the type VARCHAR(12). I wonder why the hell the numbers are sorted after the letters. Every other system including UTF-8 always begins with numbers.

[image]

Comment: Try "ORDER BY [COLLATION_KEY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-collation-key)(KEY, '...')" with some appropriate collation name...

Comment: Not ANSI SQL nor does it provide pagination functionality!

Comment: How would `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY KEY)` and `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY expr (KEY))` provide different pagination capabilities (that is, one of them provides it, and another one doesn't)? `expr` means some expression / function of `KEY`. Do you really need "ANSI SQL" label on your code to make it resolve your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a solution you can do is to take advantage of the EBCDIC character order.
**Special characters are sorted before the letters!**

If the numeric values are replaced, for example, like 0 -> .0, the sorting automatically works correctly. As this means there is no "conversion" to ASCII involved it's also not so expensive if a lot data is sorted.

| RAW_DATA | CONVERTED FOR ROW_NUMBER | ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | .0.0.1 |
| A1C | A.1C | .0.1AF |
| 0A1 | .0A.1 | .0A.1 |
| 001 | .0.0.1 | .0A.1B |
| A01 | A.0.1 | .1.0A |
| 10A | .1.0A | A.0.1 |
| ADFG | ADFG | A.0B.1.1 |
| 01AF | .0.1AF | A.1C |
| 0A1B | .0A.1B | AB.0.1.0 |
| BA0 | BA.0 | ABC |
| A0B11 | A.0B.1.1 | BA.0 |
| AB010 | AB.0.1.0 | ADFG |

And the query for that:

```
SELECT FOO.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(KEY, '0', '.0'),'1', '.1'),'2', '.2'),'3', '.3'),'4', '.4'),'5', '.5'),'6', '.6'),'7', '.7'),'8', '.8'),'9', '.9') ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM FOO
```

Answer (score 4):

DB2 is likely using EBCDIC as it's default character set for sorting, which has numbers after letters:
http://astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html

Comment: But is there a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know DB2 very well, so I can't say - hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: You can set what encoding to use with the table when you create it, which would change how it's sorting the data (basically converting the string to the ASCII/EBCIDIC values and sorting that). Search for `CCSID encoding-scheme` on this page: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-create-table. This cannot be altered after creation.

Comment: You could also use the [`ASCII_STR`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-ascii-str-asciistr) function in your order by to convert the string to the ASCII character set for ordering.

Comment: But isn't that very expensive?

Comment: Following the EBCDIC encoding I could replace any "number" with a dot and the number itself in the string and sort on that. Because special characters like dots come first in the encoding shouldn't that do the trick? So 001 will be .0.0.1 and ABC will be still ABC